# Extract image through HTTP request

Tags: c#, image, http, extract

There is a website that every time you refresh it there will be a new random picture.

I want to extract this image, how can I do it? is it possible with HTTP requests? if not there is another way to do it?

I cannot show any code because I don't know how to do it so I didn't write any code

Comment: May very well depend on the website to generate pictures

Comment: pretty much every web site has a different design, so there is no universal solution

Comment: and if I know which website I want? @Hursey

Comment: Show us the source of the page generated after you make the web request. So open the page in question in your browser and then go View Source and post the results here.